# Android dialog show top & left

Tags: android, dialog

I want to dialog appears in center 
I use this code .

```
public void dialog(View v){
    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dl_search);
    d.setCancelable(true);
    d.show();
}
```

**Appear the dialog in center .**
![1][1]
**But when I add this code  .**

```
d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),blurbitmap));
```

**The dialog appear in top & left  .**
![2][2]
....

**I want to be dialog in center  ** 
**Thanks for help**

[1]: http:// i.stack.imgur.com/UPT3S.jpg

[2]: http:// i.stack.imgur.com/K0G1w.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Window window = customdialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

or Try:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```